# FSCHateoasBundle configuration in yaml

Tags: symfony, hateoas, jmsserializerbundle, fschateoasbundle

I'm trying to use FSCHateoasBundle to add links to my API output.

The documentation mentions the possibility to configure relations using annotations or yaml but I cannot figure out where to place the yaml configuration and how it should be structured. Annotations as documented work fine. Has anyone an example?

What I try to do is to add a "relations" section in the configuration-files that are used by JMSSerializer. Do I have to use separate config-files for FSCHateoasBundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FSCHateoasBundle yaml configuration has to be done in another file than the JMSSerializerBundle.

To add metadata to your `Acme\FooBundle\Entity\User` with the JMSSerializerBundle, you'd create a file in `src/Acme/FooBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.User.yml`.

With the FSCHateoasBundle, the file would be `src/Acme/FooBundle/Resources/config/hateoas/Entity.User.yml`.

I'll add a note in the readme ;-)